# Light 3D Web graphics library for Python

Tags: python, web, 3d

I have a 3D game I want to write, and I want it to be accessible over the Web. Performance is not important: it is a turn-based game, and the number of graphical objects will be < 1000. Simplicity is important: I really don't want to spend 40 lines of code making my way through a vast array of options in order to just do something. Which is why I'm not rushing out to use OpenGL. Anyone seen a good option for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this, just discovered it, but it looks very promising. Not so great on the simplicity, but a path from Python to 3D web graphics.

https://discourse.panda3d.org/t/panda3d-webgl-port/14858